# How to "push" a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm mainly an iOS developer learning Android development and fragments. I have this class :

```
public class MyTableFragment extends ListFragment
{
    List<String> dataList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  
    Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        dataList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        dataList.add("Row 1");
        dataList.add("Row 2");
        dataList.add("Row 3");
        dataList.add("Row 4");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(),
               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataList);  
        setListAdapter(adapter);  

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
        if(position == 0) {
            // What to do here? 
            // I have a MyNewFragment() class that I want to push
        }
    }
}
```

Now basically in `onListItemClick` I want to do something like this (that's what I do in iOS) :

```
MyNewViewController *newViewController = [[MyNewViewController alloc] init];
[[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController] animated:YES];
```

I used to it like this in Android before, when I was using Activity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyNewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

But it looks like now I'd better use Fragments instead and I have no idea of how to do it. Thanks

Comment: what's wrong with starting a new Activity?

Comment: I suggest you read more about using Fragments. Your Fragments should define callback interfaces which are implemented by the parent Activity. The Activity should be responsible for replacing (or adding) Fragments based on calls to the callback interfaces' methods.

Comment: @ps Starting a new activity is a pain when you are using navigation drawer and top bar. And it makes also no sense to re-create a new activity, drawer and top bar when it's already existing (but that's a Java thing to use a lot of memory for nothing). Google recommends to use fragments, but does not provide a simple way to display them. Nothing make sense in this Android API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to show a new fragment inside your itemClick method. You could use something like this.

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
Fragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();//the fragment you want to show
profileFragment.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentTransaction
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, profileFragment);//R.id.content_frame is the layout you want to replace
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**Update** From the comments:

As a general rule a Fragment shouldn't handle the code for replacing itself with another Fragment. It should be done by communicating with the Activity and the Activity should handle it. Fragments should be self-contained and not know about other Fragments. If a Fragment has code for replacing itself with another specific Fragment, it will mean that Fragment will not be re-usable as it should be.

Comment: As a general rule a Fragment shouldn't handle the code for replacing itself with another Fragment. It should be done by communicating with the Activity and the Activity should handle it. Fragments should be self-contained and not know about other Fragments. If a Fragment has code for replacing itself with another specific Fragment, it will mean that Fragment will not be re-usable as it should be.

Comment: @Squonk you are right but I only wanted to show simplest intent alternative to fragment. I will update my answer with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can still host your `Fragment` inside `MyNewActivity`, either by incorporating it into the layout XML file using `<fragment />` tag, or by manually instantiating it and adding into the layout. This will also be the proper approach from UX point of view.